# Tensorflow netwrok parameters nog updating

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, artificial-intelligence

## Iris dataset classification, network parameters not updating

Hey, i tried to build a classifier with a logistic regression netwrok but my parameters are not updating, my weights,bias,output and cost stay the same can somebody help me? I have no idea why my parameters are not updating how can I solve this? Thank you!

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Laurens-Wissels/Desktop/iris.csv')

x = np.array(df[["sepal_length","sepal_width","petal_length","petal_width"]])
scaler_model = MinMaxScaler()
x = scaler_model.fit_transform(x)
y = df["species"]


def yvalue(y):
    if y =="setosa":
        return [1,0,0]
    elif y == "versicolor":
        return [0,1,0]
    else:
        return [0,0,1]

y = y.apply(yvalue)
y = y.reshape(150,1)
x_train, x_test , y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
print(y_train)

n_features = 4
n_species = 1
traing_epochs = 2000
learning_rate = 0.0001
n_samples = 105
display_step = 50


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[105,n_features])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[105,1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features,n_species]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))

_y = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W),b)
output = tf.nn.softmax(_y)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(Y - output , 2))/(2*n_samples)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(traing_epochs):

    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y: y_train}) # Take a gradient descent step using our inputs and labels
    sess.run(output,feed_dict={X: x_train, Y: y_train})

    # That's all! The rest of the cell just outputs debug messages. 
    # Display logs per epoch step
    if (i) % display_step == 0:
        cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y:y_train})

        print("_y:",_y)
        print("output:",output)
        print("w:",sess.run(W, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y:y_train}))
        print "Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=",sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y:y_train})  #, \"W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)
        print("-------------------------------------")

        plotData.append(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y:y_train})  )

print "Optimization Finished!"
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_train, Y:y_train})
print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'
plt.plot(plotData)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`tf.nn.softmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) divides by the sum of the exponentiated elements (see the expression in the docs). If you only have one element in the dimension being summed over (last by default):

```
print(_y.shape)
```

> (105, 1)

Then you end up with `exp(x) / sum(exp(x))`, which is a constant 1. So the gradient is 0 and therefore no training.

You could switch to [`tf.nn.sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid).